# Can I inherit a Time Machine backup if I clone my HD?

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule, leopard, superduper

I have an old Power Mac G5 running OS X 10.5.8 (The newest OS it can run). It is backed up regularly using Time Machine to my Time Capsule.

The main drive is 500 GB but I would like to replace it with a 1 TB drive by cloning it, possibly with SuperDuper. Is it possible to trick Time Machine to continuing on with the same sparsebundle rather than starting a fresh, new backup? I don't have much space left on my Time Capsule so a whole new backup would be difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Time machine uses the UUID (drive ID) to identify the source disk. So, inheriting time machine backup to continue with the swapped Mac machine is not possible rather you can use this command:

```
sudo tmutil associatedisk -a
```

Moreover, you can create an image of time machine partition and restore the data from the created image.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean. What does the command do?