# disable Time Machine scripts

Tags: macos, time-machine

My 2013 iMac was recalled by the factory for some issue with the drive. The drive was changed and I started afresh - I thought. It turns out that I was running some schedule on Time Machine which updated every time there was a change in file parameters. Which means always. One adviser suggests that this old script has been transported onto the new drive, but now I can't get to it to stop it. I do not run Time Machine and make all my back-ups by another program.

Does anyone have any idea if anything can be done to fix it?

Comment: Is Time Machine activated in System Preferences?

Comment: Hi Patrix,sorry for late response.

Comment: Time Machine is not activated.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is just toggle off time machine. The scripts are for people that want to inherit an old backup folder when they continue to use time machine.

See `tmutil inheritbackup` command line tool for details and the manual page.

- https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/tmutil.8.html
- [Can I inherit a Time Machine backup if I clone my HD?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97955/)

> Inheriting is typically only one step in the process of configuring a backup for use by a machine. You may also need to use **setdestination**, **associatedisk**, or both, depending on the situation.